# How can I replace a search ?athing=something with /athing/something?

Tags: url, friendly-url

On scratch.mit.edu, they use scratch.mit.edu/projects/*projectID* to display dynamic pages. I am working on a Scratch redesign and am wondering how to do this without doing something like scratchredesign.com/projects?id=382. And if you don't know how to not use ?=, how *would* I use it?

Basically, how can I make a website when if you go to scratchredesign.com/projects/352 it will show an embed of a Scratch project with the ID of 352, and this will work for any ID like scratchredesign.com/projects/4019271 or scratchredesign.com/projects/53234.

(I know you use avascript, I don't know if PHP though.)

Comment: Google pretty URLs and mod_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess mod_rewrite if you are running on apache or Create NGINX Rewrite Rules if on Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you are accessing the site's URLs like scratchredesign.com/projects/352, then you can try setting the `iframe` source according to `window.location.pathname` which would return "/projects/352" as a string for you to use. You can then easily set the `src` attribute for the `iframe` dynamically with a script at the bottom of the body.

The iframe:

```
<iframe name="site" id="site" height="900" width="750"></iframe>
```

The script at the end of the body, say loadIframe.js:

```
document.getElementById("site").src = "http://scratch.mit.edu" + window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: But how would you prevent it from returning 404?